# Pulseaudio issues with module-echo-cancel not cancelling audio

Tags: pulseaudio

EDIT: Ok so it appears to be working... kind of... sometimes the cancellation kicks in, other times it doesn't within the same call. This is not solved would still love some input.

---

2nd EDIT: I've posted in the Pulseaudio IRC so hopefully get some advice on this setup.

---

I have pulseaudio loading the module-echo-cancel and it doesn't seem to be working properly, or it is and I'm not doing something right... I honestly have no way to confirm which I suppose is my first issue.

My architecture is fairly simple, I have a windows 10 machine that I'm rdp'ing into from Linux.

Default source:

- ATR (with echo cancel at HDMI)

Default Sink:

- HDMI (with echo cancel at ATR)

I shouldn't think that remote access would affect the cancellation as it's still being processed locally from the HDMI speakers directly into the microphone, both of which are local devices.

Here is how I am loading module-echo-cancel in ~/.config/pulse/default.pa and I can only assume it is loading given that I can see the devices (as listed above) in `pasystray`.

```
.ifexists module-echo-cancel.so
load-module module-echo-cancel source_master=alsa_input.usb-Conference_USB_microphone_ATR4697-USB-00.mono-fallback sink_master=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_03.0.hdmi-stereo source_name=echocancel sink_name=echocancel1
set-default-source echocancel
set-default-sink echocancel1
.endif
```

Are there any extra controls I need to consider or should this work OOTB? I can't see anything in the manual that could be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you intend to do voice chat on your PulseAudio Linux computer, using

- the USB microphone as your audio source, and
- the HDMI as your audio sink.

The HDMI sink is played on speakers, and you want to prevent the speaker audio from feeding back into your microphone during calls.

I do not think that the RDP part is relevant for the issue.

Yes, PulseAudio should be able to do this. Source: Personal experience with a similar setup.
In particular, I am using a USB web cam and analog output to a hi-fi system for voice and video chats, and it works so well that I can play cooperative multiplayer games with others without the need of headphones.

The way you are setting up echo cancellation between your source and sink looks good for a basic starting point, that is exactly how it works conceptually.

As I understand it, the `default.pa` configuration is processed at PulseAudio startup. If the USB microphone is present at that point in time, then it should work. If it isn't, or if you unplug it, I assume that the echo cancellation module is not loaded / is unloaded because there is no source master, and it is not automatically re-applied when you plug the USB device in again.

So maybe you need some sort of user space daemon that reacts to the USB microphone becoming available again, and that then re-applies the echo cancellation.

**(Disclaimer: Promotion of own work)**

I did not find a such a daemon application, so I wrote one myself, [pulse-autoconf](https://eomanis.duckdns.org/permshare/pulse-autoconf/).

As of now it is only packaged for Arch Linux.

I have managed to successfully run it on a Ubuntu 20.04 computer by manually copying the script and other files onto that machine to their expected directories. The only known thing that does not work is its convenience feature to print a table view of the current sinks and sources, because Ubuntu ships a different `column` application than Arch.

It might work for you, or it might not.
In any case its web page might provide you with additional insights around PulseAudio echo cancellation.

Comment: Oh wow that's awesome. Ok great that's good to know I'm doing it right, coz I got no response at all from the pa devs. I'll have a look at your proj and see what's going on but it appears to be mostly working but then not as well as you seem to be experiencing. In any case I'm now opting for a hardware unit that will handle AEC.